# What's slowing this Clojure function down?

Tags: java, performance, clojure

I am working on [Project Euler problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14) in Clojure. I have what I feel is a good general algorithm, and I am getting the correct result, but I am struggling to understand why my function is so slow compared to (what I believe to be) an equivalent function in Java. Here's my Clojure function to get the length of the Collatz chain from a given starting number:

```
(defn collatz-length
  [n]
  (loop [x n acc 1]
    (if (= 1 x)
      acc
      (recur (if (even? x)
               (/ x 2)
               (inc (* 3 x)))
             (inc acc)))))
```

And here's my Java function to do the same thing:

```
public static int collatzLength(long x) {
    int count = 0;
    while (x > 1) {
        if ((x % 2) == 0) {
            x = x / 2;
        } else {
            x = (x * 3) + 1;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

To time the performance of these functions, I used the following Clojure code:

```
(time (dorun (map collatz-length (range 1 1000000))))
```

And the following Java code:

```
long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();

int[] nums = new int[1000000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    nums[i] = collatzLength(i+1);
}

System.out.println("Total time (ms) : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime));
```

The Java code runs in `304 ms` on my machine, but the Clojure code takes `4220 ms`. What is causing this bottleneck and how can I improve the performance of my Clojure code?

Comment: Wow! Real programmers at work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using boxed math so numbers are constantly being boxed and unboxed. Try something like:

```
(set! *unchecked-math* true)
(defn collatz-length
  ^long [^long n]
  (loop [x n acc 1]
    (if (= 1 x)
      acc
      (recur (if (zero? (rem x 2))
               (quot x 2)
               (inc (* 3 x)))
             (inc acc)))))
 (time (dorun (loop [i 1] (when (< i 1000000) (collatz-length i) (recur (inc i))))))
```

Comment: Nice! That reduced my time down to a more reasonable `650 ms`. I noticed you also changed my `/` to `quot`, which ended up being the biggest performance improvement. Why is `quot` more efficient?

Comment: `quot` is defined to do truncating integer division, so it can compile down to a single JVM bytecode operation (provided the right typehints are given). `/` returns fractions, so it can't take advantage of those `^long` typehints: it has to worry that you might try to divide an odd number by two, in which case it needs to give you back a fraction.

Comment: Based on amalloy's comment above, I replaced `even?` with `(zero? (rem x 2))` which can use all prims and that seems to be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Alex's answer, you can speed things up a bit more by inlining the call to `even?` (that function doesn't support unboxed integers):

```
(defn collatz-length
  ^long [^long n]
  (loop [x n acc 1]
    (if (= 1 x)
      acc
      (recur (if (zero? (bit-and x 1))
               (quot x 2)
               (inc (* 3 x)))
             (inc acc)))))
```

For reference, https://www.refheap.com/cfd421430653cf786177f3cfe is the bytecode produced by your java method (changed to use `long` instead of `int`), and the bytecode produced by my clojure function. They look very, very similar, except for an introductory stanza in which the clojure version copies the input argument n into x, where the java version just overwrites the existing n.

Comment: no, it's because you used n instead of x for the loop check. :)

Comment: Aha, thanks @Alex. That's what I get for posting an answer right as I'm leaving for dinner. With that fix made (edited into my answer), I get a further 4x speedup from your code, and all reflection and boxing is gone: it should be basically the same bytecode as the java version expands to.

Comment: Interestingly on my machine I get a 10% improvement on @amalloy's code if I replace `quot x 2` by `bit-shift-right x 1`. I wonder why the jvm / cpu is not optimizing that.

Comment: @diego Because they're not the same for negative x. eg, for x = -1, shifting yields -1, but quot yields 0 (integer division rounds toward 0 in java).

Comment: I guess the CPU has no way of knowing whether it's dealing with signed or unsigned values. If they were guaranteed to be unsigned then it could optimize that. On the other hand the JVM could know that division by 2 in a loop with positive values could be optimized to bit shift.

Comment: Never mind, it's not a constant loop so the JVM would have to do too much guesswork to know that x is always positive and can be treated as unsigned.